# Как правильно разделить авторизованного пользователя от неавторизованного?

Tags: php

Начну с небольшой истории. Был у нас объект авторизованного пользователя (`User`), и `null`. И всегда мы проверяли

```
if (!$user)
```

Но была проблема, для неавторизованного пользователя было где-то 5 значений по-умолчанию и их приходилось всегда тянуть и получалось так, что вместо передачи 1-ого объекта с данными, приходилось в любом случае передавать N параметром, либо полученные из объекта типа `User`, либо взятые из констант.

И тогда решили мы применить `NullObject (Guest`) и выделили интерфейс из `User`'а, под названием `UserInterface`. И добавили мы метод `UserInterface::isAuth` для проверки на то авторизован ли Пользователь. И стали получать мы из сервиса не `User|null`, а всегда `UserInterface` и все наладилось, стали везде передавать объект и никогда не проверять на `null`, но пришла новая напасть...

Методы, которым не было разницы авторизован ли пользователь или нет, принимали `UserInterface` и были счастливы, но вот те, которым была разница принимали объект типа `User`. И тут есть небольшая проблема, ведь проверив объект типа `UserInterface` на `isAuth`, он не становится объектом `User` и IDE ругается, говоря о том, что метод принимает объект типа `User`, а мы ему даем всего лишь `UserInterace`. И как-то это не очень приятно. Хотя все работает нормально, потому что если метод `isAuth` вернул `true`, то это косвенно означает, что этот объект является типом `User`.

Как решить сию делему? Где мы были не правы? Может быть мы неправильно решили эту проблему?

Одно из решений, это сделать дополнительный метод в сервисе получения Пользователей, который будет возвращать `User` или `null`, и получается, что мы вернулись к тому, что начали, но в меньших размерах...

Comment: Пусть они принимают UserInterface, у которого есть метод isAuthorized(). А еще лучше - полностью разделить логику работы с юзером и с его правами, и передавать вообще разные объекты (объект, представляющий собой пользователя, и *контекст авторизации*).

Comment: @Etki могут принимать, но тогда везде придется проверять на isAuthorized, а передачей и ожиданием типа User, проверка не нужна (но я согласен с тем, что это решит нашу проблему). Насчет прав, у нас их нет, есть только неавторизованный пользователь и авторизованный и все. Для авторизованного пользователя доступен кабинет и вот вся разница. Да и контекст авторизации в нашем случае избыточен.

Comment: А для чего вы тогда определяли интерфейс `UserInterface`, если все равно методы принимают `User`?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev но не все методы, а процентов 30 принимают User'а, а все остальные UserInterface

Comment: Зачем такие костыли?! Раз вы вводите `UserInterface`, то и программируйте на основе интерфейсов, а не реализаций.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev но как же быть с ясностью и понятноостью, вот принимает метод на вход User'а и сразу понятно, что нужно его где-то достать, а если принимает этот же метод UserInterface, и чтобы понять что нужен именно авторизованный пользователь, нужно прочитать документацию к методу или что-то типа того... Как быть с этим?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас логика работы с пользователями плохо спроектирована. Если вы определяете интерфейс `UserInterface`, то **любая** его реализация может быть использована как объект пользователя. Ваша архитектура рушит принцип инкапсуляции.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да, спроектировано не очень, и да опирается на конкретную реализацию... Но как тогда сделать это лучше и чтобы осталась понятность при использовании?

Comment: В идеале, все что использует пользователей, должно работать с любой реализацией `UserInterface` (`NullUser`, `User`, `TestUserMock`, ...). Знаю, что сказать проще, чем сделать, но, на мой взгляд, это самое правильное решение.

Comment: Почитав документацию symfony2 увидел что они сами возвращают null, и может быть мы были неправы избавившись от null'а, и стоит использовать другую тактику